# Accessing variables in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

So I have an object:

```
settings: {
    navBar: $(".navbar");
    dropdown: navBar.find(".dropdown");
}
```

However this throws the error `navBar` is not defined.  Using `this.navBar` does not seem to work either.

Any insight into why this isn't working and the proper way to access the variable would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `var navBar = $(".navbar");
...
...
settings: {
    navBar: navBar;
    dropdown: navBar.find(".dropdown");
}`

Comment: It's because you don't even have an object there.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to actually help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you're having trouble referring to sibling properties when you're defining an object, like this:

```
var example = {
    a: 1,
    b: a + 1 // <-- a is undefined
};
```

This is because `a` or `this.a` here would refer to the property `a` within the scope defining `example`.

You could try something like this:

```
function prepareSettings(navNode)
{
    return {
        navBar: navNode,
        dropdown: navNode.find(".dropdown")
    };
}

var settings = prepareSettings( $(".navbar") );
```

Or create a getter type method within `settings`, wherin `this` refers to the `settings` object and has access to its `navBar` property:

```
var settings = {
    navBar: $(".navbar"),
    getDropdown: function()
    {
        return this.navBar.find(".dropdown");
    }
};
```

A clearer example of the issue you're having could be demonstrated like so:

```
var a = 5;
var test = {
    a: 3,
    b: a
};


// Output is 5 rather than 3, which you might have
// been expecting instead.
console.log(test.b);
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains it for me.  I didn't know you couldn't access sibling variables.  While annoying, at least I'm not doing anything stupid which is a relief.

Comment: @user2297440 It might seem annoying at the moment, but as you progress you'll eventually realize it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `navBar` property can't be accessed from inside the object literal declaration. You'll have to do something like this:

```
var navBar = $(".navbar"),
    settings = {
        navBar: navBar,
        dropdown: navBar.find(".dropdown")
    };
```

Declare `navBar` as a local variable, then refer to it from inside your object declaration.